# building js apps with ant

Tags: javascript, ant

I'm stuck on a couple of points trying to build JS apps with ant.

- there is a dir called `src` and each dir inside that is a "mini-app". When I loop through each dir using `subant`, how can I get the name of the dir relative to src (without the full path), so far I've got `<property name="app" location="." />` but this prints out `C:\etc\etc\src\miniapp` instead of just `miniapp`
- there is an `<apply>` being run on all javascript template files, where a rhino script pre-compiles template strings into template functions, I'm using `outputproperty` to capture `print(...)` but if I try to use the property after the apply task it only holds the output of the very last template file. This is the task in full

  ```
  <target name="compile-jst">
      <apply dir="build" executable="java" outputproperty="templates">
          <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.jst" />
          <arg line="-jar rhino.jar compile-jst.js" />
          <srcfile />
      </apply>
  </target>
  ```

Thanks.

---

**Update** solved first point:

```
<basename file="${basedir}" property="app" />
```

Still stuck with `<apply>` output concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name of a directory or file resource without the full path, use `<basename>`

To concatenate output from running `<apply>` on multiple files, be sure to use `append=true`.